# Undefined argument evaluation order is causing trouble when forwarding unique_ptr

Tags: c++

I know that the order of function argument evaluation is undefined in C++, but here's the situation I've reached.

```
class LibraryWidget {
    int data ();
}

class LibraryContainer {
    LibraryContainer (std :: unique_ptr <LibraryWidget>, int parameter);
}

class ApplicationContainer : public LibraryContainer {
    ApplicationContainer (std :: unique_ptr <LibraryWidget> ptr)
    : LibraryContainer (std :: move (ptr), calc_parameter (ptr -> data ()))
    {
    }
}
```

`ApplicationContainer` wants to tidy up the interface because it knows how to `calc_parameter`, but, if I'm reading the standard correctly, it is unspecified whether `ptr` has already been moved by the time `calc_ptr`'s argument is called, so `ptr` might be null.

Here's the workaround I'm thinking of now

```
private:
ApplicationContainer (LibraryWidget * ptr)
: LibraryContainer (std :: unique_ptr <LibraryWidget> (ptr), calc_parameter (ptr -> data ()))
{
}

public:
ApplicationContiner (std :: unique_ptr <LibraryWidget> (ptr))
: ApplicationContainer (ptr .release ())
{
}
```

but somehow I feel like there's going to be another way to do it without redirecting the whole constructor like this. I couldn't instantly recommend this solution to someone because it has to be adapted for exception safety (as-is it possibly leaks if calc_parameter throws).

I would like some more bullets in my gun for when problems like this come up again, which  they will, and ideally which do not involve losing pointer encapsulation, even temporarily.

So, even though I have a solution, for the purposes of education, how else might you solve this?